# Проблема с железом

Tags: железо

Компьютер не включается. На материнскую плату питание идет. При нажатии кнопки включения кулер делает несколько оборотов и больше никакой реакции. Не подскажете почему?

Comment: Ремонт и обслуживание электроники не входят в допустимую тематику сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть много. Попробуйте отключить все устройства от материнской платы: жесткие диски, CD, видеокарту. Т.е. оставьте одну материнскую плату, посмотрите запустится ли кулер. Если запустится, тогда можно подключать все устройства по очереди, чтобы смотреть на чем перестает запускаться. При этом вам будут выдаваться звуковые сигналы. Значение их можно посмотреть [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B_BIOS). Если ничего не получается, возьмите где-нибудь другой блок питания и попробуйте с ним. Если заработает, то проблема в блоке питания. Если нет, то проблема с материнской платой.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала можно опробовать скинуть биос вытащить батарейку и обесточить блок питания. Вообще тут причин масса. После чего такое произошло?

Answer (score -1):

Либо материнская плата издохла, либо блок питания.